# MOSS Workflow with InfoPath forms - Redirect after submit

Tags: moss, workflow, infopath

I have a MOSS workflow that uses InfoPath forms.
After submitting the form, MOSS saves the information and redirects the user to a list of items.

Is there a way to control where the user is redirected after the InfoPath form is saved?
I'd like to redirect him to another page of my MOSS site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Source" parameter within the query string; you'll be redirected to that page after the form closes.

Ex.

http://spserver/finance/Invoices/986.xml?&Source=http://spserver/finance/Pages/approvals.aspx&OpenIn=Browser

Comment: My infopath form is actually a workflow task. Where can I set the source attribute in that case?

Comment: Are you building the WF with Visual Studio?